# Can't access to event posted values

Tags: post, google-apps-script

i'm writing a little google apps script which allow to select several names among a list of developpers. But in my doPost(e) method, i can't access to the array of posted values (it's undefinded), event if i check all the checkboxes...

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // add the new menu
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Edit page", functionName: "start"})
  ss.addMenu("My tools", menuEntries);
}


function start() {

  var app  = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("Edit page");
  var formPanel = app.createFormPanel();
  var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var gridPanel = app.createGrid(1, 2);

  // developpers
  var developperPanel = app.createVerticalPanel()
  var developpers = [];
  developpers.push( "John", "Peter", "Max", "Johnny" );
  for (var i = 1; i < developpers.length; ++i) {
    var checkbox = app.createCheckBox(developpers[i]).setName("dev"+i);
    developperPanel.add(checkbox);
  }
  gridPanel.setWidget(0,0,app.createLabel("Developpers : "));
  gridPanel.setWidget(0,1,developperPanel);

  // submit button
  mainPanel.add(gridPanel);
  mainPanel.add(app.createSubmitButton().setText("OK"));
  formPanel.add(mainPanel);
  app.add(formPanel);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.show(app);
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel(e.values[0])); // Here is the error.       
  return app;
}
```

In the exemple, the list is fixed but in my real script, i create the list thanks to the Spreadsheet.

Thanks

Max

Comment: have you tried to name your start function 'doGet' ? I think it is mandatory...

Comment: yes, l tried but it didn't work. However, i can access to the sended values if i call 'e.parameter.dev1'.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't understand exactly what you try to do... could you post your `doPost(e)` function ?

Comment: The doPost(e) function is in my first message, it allow to show the result of the post. I want to access to the parameters by their index or by their Name, because i don't know how many developpers i would have in my list. But i've found a solution, the attribute isn't 'values[index]' but parameter[name]. I'm gonna show my solution in the answer of this question.
I'm not very understandable...

Comment: I don't know where you got the impression that your checkboxes would be under `e.values`. Each checkbox value is under its name on `e.parameter`, like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to see the checkboxes values is using `e.parameter[name]`, like you said yourself on a comment. Here is some code example:

```js
function start() {
  //...
  var developpers = ["John", "Peter", "Max", "Johnny"];
  //you were skiping the first developer
  for (var i = 0; i < developpers.length; ++i) { //array starts on zero, not one
    var checkbox = app.createCheckBox(developpers[i]).setName("dev"+i);
    developperPanel.add(checkbox);
  }
  //...
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var developpers = ["John", "Peter", "Max", "Johnny"]; //repeat it here or make it global, if it's static like this
  var checked = [];
  for( var i in developpers )
    if( e.parameter['dev'+i] == 'true' )
      checked.push(developpers[i]);
  app.add(app.createLabel(checked));
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Henrique, i've already found the solution but i can't answer my own question until several hours. I haven't seen docs about parameter[name] on the Google documentation, just parameter.name. I found it by chance.

Comment: This is how JavaScript works; it is not related specifically to Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `e.parameter.yourCheckBoxName`

for example:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel(e.parameter.dev1); // Access checkbox by its name
  return app;
}
```

This would show status of check box "Peter", when it is checked. You can modify based on your need.

Comment: I have not tested it, but I'm pretty confident that the checkbox "return value" will be true/false or true/undefined. But not its text.

Comment: @Henrique Abreu, you are right. It would not include chekboxes in the parameter, if they were unchecked. Which means that, if you tried to access those check box, that would return undefined. On the other side, checked box which were checked, would have value "on" instead of "true".

Comment: I found very weird what you said about this "on" value, as I didn't remembered it at all. I went and tested it now and turns out you're wrong indeed. It values returned are always "true" or "false", as strings, not "on" (or undefined, as I also suggested).

Comment: Moreover, the solution can't be applied on my script. I don't know how many checkbox will be generated by the script (in my example, the list is fixed but i generate it in my script). I need a loop and i can do it with parameter["dev"+i], i can't on parameter.dev1.